# Configure RowGateway and Adapter using Zend\Di

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use the rewritten DB-Component in Zend Framework (Beta 3) together with Zend\Di.

But when I try to configure Adapter, TableGateway, ResultsSet and RowGateway using DI I'm getting an CircularDependencyException.

Here is my Config:

```
            'Parser\Model\DocumentTable' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'tableName'             => 'cms_documents',
                    'adapter'               => 'masterdb',
                    'selectResultPrototype' => 'Parser\Model\ResultSet\Document',
                ),
            ),

            'Parser\Model\ResultSet\Document' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'rowObjectPrototype' => 'Parser\Model\Row\Document'
                )
            ),

            'Parser\Model\Row\Document' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'tableGateway'  => 'Parser\Model\DocumentTable',
                    'primaryKey'    => 'doc_pid',
                ),
            ),
```

Is there a other way to configure a TableGateway with custom ResultSet and Row?